# django rest m2m serializers throw Bad request error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models: Task and Scenario:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks', blank=True, )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project_tasks' )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    ...

class Scenario(models.Model):
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='scenarios', blank=True,)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)
```

Their serialzers:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks')
        instance = Scenario.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_data.get('id'))
            instance.tasks.add(task)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks', [])
        instance = super().update(instance, alidated_data)
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_data.get('id'))
            instance.tasks.add(task)
        return instance
```

And view to perform CRUD operations on both these models:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def task_list(request):

    tasks = []
    """
    List all tasks, or create a new task.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #get all the tasks in  aspecific project
        if request.query_params.get('projectId'):
            # get a specific project 
            projectId = request.query_params.get('projectId')
            project = Project.objects.get(id=projectId)
            tasks = project.project_tasks.all()
            serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)    
        else:
            tasks = Task.objects.filter(stakeholder=request.user)
            serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(stakeholder=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def task_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Get, udpate, or delete a specific task
    """
    try:
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        task.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

for scenario:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def scenarios_list(request):

    scenarios = []

    """
    List all scenarios, or create a new.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # get projects of a specific stakeholder
        if request.query_params.get('stakeholderId'):
            stakeholderId = request.query_params.get('stakeholderId')
            scenarios = Scenario.objects.filter(stakeholder=stakeholderId)
            serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenarios, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            scenarios = Scenario.objects.all()
            serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenarios, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ScenarioSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(stakeholder=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def scenario_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Get, udpate, or delete a specific scenarios
    """
    try:
        scenario = Scenario.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Project.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenario)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenario, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(
                serilizer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        scenario.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The idea is Tasks will be created first and then a scenario can be created by attaching a few tasks to it.

Scenario creation is successful but since I implemented logic of scenarios, task creation and updation stated failing throwing me Bad request error.

request looks like following:

```
{project: "6", title: "Fourteen", how_often: "", how_important_task: "", role: "", …}
```

Do I need to update the task serializer as well? What is going wrong?

**UPDATE:** If I comment `id = serializers.IntegerField()`in TaskSerializer Task creation is successful, but I need that line otherwise scenario creation fails.

Comment: what error do you have if you comment the `id` in the task serializer?

Comment: If I comment Id in taskserializer, task creatation is successful (which is independent of scenario creation) but scenario creation fails saying Task matching query not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, remove `id` from `TaskSerializer` and try it:

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_or_create_task(self, data):
        qs  = Task.objects.filter(pk=data.get('id'))
        if qs.exists():
            return qs.first()
        task = Task.objects.create(**data)
        return task

    def add_tasks(self, instance, tasks):
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = self.get_or_create_task(task_data)
            instance.tasks.add(task)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks')
        instance = Scenario.objects.create(**validated_data)
        self.add_tasks(instance, tasks)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks', [])
        instance = super().update(instance, alidated_data)
        self.add_tasks(instance, tasks)
        return instance
```

and why you don't use class base views for your app?

Comment: Actually I started with modelviewset but in my drf docs I couldn't see anything (drf version 3.8), so I switched back to function based views

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried your solution, Task and Scenario creation was successful, however Task update (PUT) failed throwing bad request, no errors on the console though

Comment: You have error on put to the Task or To the scenario with task?

Comment: try to add `print (serializer.errors)` before `status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I figured it out from error message!

Comment: glad to help you, and if you remmeber me at 2 may i try to create an example with class views for you

Comment: Great! Just as a side note: my setup is Django==1.11.12, djangorestframework==3.8.2 and drfdocs==0.0.11. With this I tried creating modelviwset (the code was correct) but in drfdocs I could not see my API end points. Maybe drfdocs does not support it yet

Comment: Hi! I just noticed that there is a problem in solution! Whenever I create a new scenario with existing tasks, those tasks are again created adding to my list of created tasks!

Comment: Looks like again as we commented the id in serializer, the line `qs  = Task.objects.filter(pk=data.get('id'))` always returns null and leads to a new task creation. Uncommenting id in TaskSerializer again actually solved the problem!

Comment: But again this creates another problem: a scenario returns all the tasks ordered according to their ids and not in the order they were created

Comment: now i can't understand details, but tomorrow i try to look it

Comment: Sure! Thanks :)

Comment: For your reference, I have created another question with all the required details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100727/django-rest-framework-m2m-serializer-returning-nested-objects-in-original-sequen