# Django rest framework M2M serializer save nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: Task and Scenario. Tasks are created beforehand and Scenarios are created afterwards by including few of the existing tasks. Important thing is in a scenario, tasks must be arranged in a specific sequence and not according to their ids.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks', blank=True, )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project_tasks' )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    ...

class Scenario(models.Model):
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='scenarios', blank=True,)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)
```

Serializers:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_or_create_task(self, data):
        qs  = Task.objects.filter(pk=data.get('id'))
        if qs.exists():
            return qs.first()
        task = Task.objects.create(**data)
        return task

    def add_tasks(self, instance, tasks):
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = self.get_or_create_task(task_data)
            instance.tasks.add(task)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks')
        instance = Scenario.objects.create(**validated_data)
        self.add_tasks(instance, tasks)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks', [])
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        self.add_tasks(instance, tasks)
        return instance
```

Few requirements I have:

While retrieving a scenario/s I wanted to retrieve corresponding task objects and not just their ids, that's why the line `id = serializers.IntegerField()` exists in TaskSerializer.

With this code a new Task is successfully created, but Task update fails at e.g.`/api/tasks/1` as it also expects id in the request body. Without `id = serializers.IntegerField()` both task creation and update is successful.

Also, without `id = serializers.IntegerField()` in TaskSerializer Scenario creation is successful and included tasks are returned in the correct order, say task3, task1, Task5. However, whichever tasks are included while scenario creation, those are created again in the database (of course with successive ids).

Uncommenting `id = serializers.IntegerField()` leads to successful scenario creation and no extra tasks are automatically created (which is good), but the scenario returns tasks in the oder of their ids i.e. if a scenario was created with Task3, task1, task5 then when you GET a scenario you get back task1, task3, task5.

Why is it happening?

**Extra Note:** I do not intend to create a task while scenario creation, tasks will always be created beforehand, and scenario will be created afterwards by attaching a few existing tasks to it

Comment: What are the criterias for ordering the tasks?

Comment: The order in which tasks are are sent in the request while creating a scenario, that order should be preserved. e.g. `{tasks:[{id=5,...},{id=2,...},{id=4, ...}]} ` then that order should be preserved. Order is preserved when I comment `id = serializers.IntegerField()` in TaskSerializer

Comment: You should gain control in your code over the order. You could create an model for the intermediate table (`through`), add a timestamp field and set up default order in the class.

Comment: to delete all exists tasks of the scenario on update action you may use `instance.tasks.all().delete()`

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to set `tasks` as `read_only` and get data from `context`, and to save the created order you may use `extra select`

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_tasks(self, obj):
        qs = obj.tasks.extra(
            select={'creation_seq': 'scenario_scenario_tasks.id'}
            ).order_by("creation_seq")
        return TaskSerializer(qs, many=True).data

    def get_or_create_task(self, data):
        qs = Task.objects.filter(pk=data.get('id'))
        if qs.exists():
            return qs.first()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        task = serializer.save()
        return task

    def add_tasks(self, instance, data):
        tasks = data.get('tasks', [])
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = self.get_or_create_task(task_data)
            instance.tasks.add(task)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        # for python 2
        # instance = super(ScenarioSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        data = self.context.get('request').data
        #      HERE ^^^^^^^^^^
        self.add_tasks(instance, data)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        # for python 2
        # instance = super(ScenarioSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        data = self.context.get('request').data
        #      HERE ^^^^^^^^^^
        self.add_tasks(instance, data)
        return instance
```

and here [drfdoc-demo](https://github.com/gitavk/drfdoc-demo) you can look on full example with class based views for drfdoc